# Variable 'resultToReturn' is not outputing value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's my code. I'm trying to send local 'result' variable from 'returnQueryToGlobal' function, but its showing as 'undefined' in console.

I tried everything, haha!

I'm running this on a simple VPS from OVH.

```
export function dbQuery(sql){
    var dbArguments = [];

    for (var i in arguments)
    {
        if (i == 0) continue;
        var escapeVarchar = mysql_real_escape_string(arguments[i]);
        console.log(escapeVarchar);
        dbArguments.push(escapeVarchar);
    }

    var resultToReturn;

    function returnQueryToGlobal(err, result)
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        resultToReturn = result;
    }
    con.query(sql, dbArguments, returnQueryToGlobal)

    console.log(resultToReturn);
    var dbArguments = null;


}
dbQuery("SELECT name FROM accounts");
```

Comment: `con.query()` is asynchronous, which mean it starts running and at some point in the future will call the callback `returnQueryToGlobal`. But that is long after you've tried to log the result. You need to handle the result inside the callback.

Comment: Thank's for reply! Where I have this callback? It's a returnQueryToGlobal function?

Comment: Yes, you pass it into `con.query()`. It will be called after the DB gets results.

Comment: Ok, in callback function I see the result. But I need return a DB result from parent function (dbQuery). It's a solution to return a value to parent function ant return it again?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are losing the reference to `resultToReturn`. Try this:

```
    con.query(sql, dbArguments, (err, result)=>{
       if (err) throw err;
        resultToReturn = result;
})
```

The reference to `resultToReturn` should still be available inside the function body.
Also, since this is an asynchronous operation, you are still going to get `undefined` when it logs. You need to handle the value inside your callback.

Since you need to return your result to another function, you need to pass another callback, with the reult as an argument, so that it becomes available in the desired context.

```
//calling the function
dbQuery(sql, (resultsToReturn)=>{
    //do stuff with the value of the result
})




 //declaring the function
 function dbQuery(callback)
  {
    con.query(sql, dbArguments, (err, result)=>{
           if (err) throw err;
            callback(result);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. dbQuery function still not returning "resultsToReturn". Maybe the problem is that it's a function inside a function and don't see return?

Comment: since the whole operation is asynchronous, you will need to pass a callback function to "dbQuery" like so: function dbQuery(sql, callback). Consider dbQuery to be the equivalent of "outerFunction" that was writen in the answer, but with the "sql" argument as well "dbQuery(sql, (results)=>{/*do stuff with the results*/});". Inside that callback declaration the results should be available for use

Comment: It's very close, it's still not what I need. I need a dbQuery function will return a result from database, but now it's still return nothing. This is for global database function for X resources to not affect about this other resources.